# Best way to reuse templates in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, single-page-application

My use case:
I want to have a nice AJAX login form. And I want to make it available in separate page and in modal window. I'm new to Angular.js and I wonder - what is the best way to reuse template of the form? Should I make a directive, or should I inject it in DOM from controller, or maybe somhow else?

Kindly help.

Comment: Directive - because you also want some behavior I suppose.

Comment: I would use a directive that interacts with a service.

Comment: @KevinB By service you mean some kind of wrapper aroung `$http` that communicates with a backend?

Comment: Yes, the service would be something that you can interact with to get information about the logged in user, to log the user in, to log the user out, etc so that all of the logic for that is in one organized place.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the tips about directive and authentication service, I was handle my issue that way. If you post this as an answer, I will accept.